# HTML Scraper which can handle AJAX

Tags: java, html, json

I want to scrape data from a website which has a text field and a button, on click of the button and according to the data in the text field a dynamic table is generated through AJAX.

I have used Jsoup for simple scraping but after researching found out that it does not support scraping of a dynamic page.

I would like to know some of the best scrapers around with the level of functionality and level of difficulty. I'm looking for free Java code; the final product is intended to run on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you code Python? If so, I have an answer for you.

Comment: Selenium is free and it has a Java version. The proposed solution is in Python since I am more comfortable with it but the Java version is very similar.

Comment: ok il hav to try out selenium before ticking your answer right, i'l also wait for more answers, hw is HTMLunit?

Comment: This solution is for Python, but you can apply the principles in JS:  http://blog.databigbang.com/web-scraping-ajax-and-javascript-sites/

Comment: @AfrozShaikh so did you try the proposed solution ?

Comment: Did it using Html unit!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is quite common. Usually a basic scraper is not able to deal with ajax content loading. You should make usage of a library which let you wait for content loading, check if element are visible and so on.

So more than a basic scraper you would need a tool for automating browser navigation.

By my experience I would suggest you the usage of the framework Selenium Webdriver (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

It is very popular on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selenium/info)

Selenium is a portable software testing framework for web browsers automation in a number of popular programming languages, including Java, C#, Ruby, Groovy, Python, PHP, and Perl. Test playback is possible in most modern web browsers. Selenium deploys on Windows, Linux, and Macintosh platforms.

A simple example of usage in python from documentation. Example with other languages here http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# go to the google home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# the page is ajaxy so the title is originally this:
print driver.title

# find the element that's name attribute is q (the google search box)
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

# type in the search
inputElement.send_keys("cheese!")

# submit the form (although google automatically searches now without submitting)
inputElement.submit()

try:
    # we have to wait for the page to refresh, the last thing that seems to be updated is the title
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("cheese!"))

    # You should see "cheese! - Google Search"
    print driver.title

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Note: In case you need an advanced scraper solution you can make usage of [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)(python library) joined with Selenium.

Comment: See also: https://bitbucket.org/djarvis/scripted-selenium/